# OpenCV, Python, findContours, number of elements in hierarchy

Tags: python, opencv

Given this minimal example code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((512,512,1), np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(img, (100,100), (200,200), 255, -1)
cv2.rectangle(img, (300,300), (400,400), 255, -1)
#cv2.imwrite('img.png', img)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    img,
    cv2.RETR_TREE,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print hierarchy
print len(hierarchy)
```

that produces the following image:

[image]

I would expect `hierarchy` to look like this

```
[[ 1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1  0 -1 -1]]
```

because the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) clearly states

```
hierarchy –
Optional output vector, containing information about the image topology.
It has as many elements as the number of contours.
For each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements
hierarchy[i][0] , hiearchy[i][1] , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3]
are set to 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours
at the same hierarchical level,
the first child contour and the parent contour, respectively.
```

But actually it looks like this:

```
[[[ 1 -1 -1 -1]
  [-1  0 -1 -1]]]
```

This means that `hierarchy` does not have 2 elements (like the documentation suggests), but only 1 element.
Thus I do not have to use

```
hierarchy[i][0]
hierarchy[i][1]
...
```

to access the data but

```
hierarchy[0][i][0]
hierarchy[0][i][1]
...
```

Is there a deeper meaning behind this that I am missing, am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation just incorrect / the function broken?

Comment: [try to read this one](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: This only explains how it is and how to use it. But it still is contrary to what the documentation states. The additional level of nesting of the hierarchy array is not explained and still does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer :)

i tried the code below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.zeros((512,512,1), np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(img, (100,100), (200,200), 255, 5)
cv2.rectangle(img, (300,300), (400,400), 255, 5)
#cv2.imwrite('img.png', img)
_,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
    img,
    cv2.RETR_TREE,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print hierarchy
print len(hierarchy)
imgBGR=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
print ('0 Blue')
cv2.drawContours(imgBGR,contours,0,(255,0,0),2)
print ('1 Purple')
cv2.drawContours(imgBGR,contours,1,(255,0,255),2)
print ('2 Red')
cv2.drawContours(imgBGR,contours,2,(0,0,255),2)
print ('3 Green')
cv2.drawContours(imgBGR,contours,3,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('imgBGR',imgBGR)
cv2.waitKey()
```

which outputs

[image]

lets check:

`hierarchy[0] [ 2 -1  1 -1]`

`hierarchy[Blue] [ Next is Red, Previous is none,  First_Child is Purple,  Parent is none]`

`hierarchy[1] [-1 -1 -1  0]`

`hierarchy[Purple] [ Next is none, Previous is none,  First_Child is none,  Parent is Blue]`

`hierarchy[2] [-1  0  3 -1]`

`hierarchy[Red] [ Next is none, Previous is Blue,  First_Child is Green,  Parent is none]`

`hierarchy[3] [-1 -1 -1  2]`

`hierarchy[Green] [ Next is none, Previous is none,  First_Child is none,  Parent is Red]`